# WordNet Java API

Tags: java, api, wordnet

I'm having to use a Java API for WordNet, it will be for a big implementation. I'm searching but coming across many;

1. JWordNet(http://sourceforge.net/projects/jwordnet/)
2. MIT Java WordNet Interface (http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/)
3. RiTa WordNet(http://rednoise.org/rita/wordnet/documentation/index.htm)

can i get some advise about which one is better?

Comment: Did you take a look at [Idilia's Language Graph](http://www.idilia.com/developer/language-graph/next-generation-wordnet/). For real-applications, you will find the content much more complete than Wordnet. There is a Web API with Java examples.

Comment: Hi Noor. So which one you found better?

Comment: Only #2 supports WordNet versions older than 2.0 (a necessary feature for my project) but it's much slower than what I used before (JAWS: http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/index.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter)

Comment: @user495285 have used all three with wordnet 3.0.

Comment: EDIT: MIT implementation is as fast; it was a bug in my program.
@AmitG: it is older versions that I'm having problems with most of these APIs. Support for newer versions of WN is generally good.

Comment: More suitable for Software Recommendations?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can refer to the paper [Java Libraries for Accessing the PrincetonWordnet: Comparison and Evaluation](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/download.php?f=finlayson.2014.procgwc.7.x.pdf) which compares 12 Java libraries for accessing WordNet. It compares their performance and other features.